# Android : changing tab name - nullPointerException

Tags: android, tabs

I'm simply trying to change my tabs name because I included layout in my tabs and I can't change the name in the XML or at least I can't find how.

This is the layout (part of):

```
<FrameLayout
android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="360dp"
android:layout_above="@+id/button_gamecfg_save" >

<include
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
layout="@layout/gamecfg_times" />

<include
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
layout="@layout/gamecfg_others" />

<include
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
layout="@layout/gamecfg_roles" />

</FrameLayout>
```

And my code :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gamecfg_tabs);
    TabHost th=((TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost));
    ((TextView)th.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).findViewById(android.R.id.title)).setText("New"); //<--------------------
}
```

In my code I have a nullPointerException at the marked line. I can get the tabwidget easily but as soon as I try to getChildAt I have the exception but I don't understand why.

Can you help me ?

Comment: try `setIndicator("Data")` instead of `setText("New")`

Comment: Put the breakpoint and check what you are getting for "th".

Comment: I'm getting the error at GetChildAt and it's because the tabwidget has no child but its not possible is it ? I have 3 layout added in, the SDK shows me 3 tabs ! How is this happening ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to call the method th.setup() before getChildAt(0)?

The documentation says:
"Call setup() before adding tabs if loading TabHost using findViewById()."